# Why AJAX response 0!

Tags: plugins, ajax

It is irritating me why AJAX response is 0 !. I want to check  whether the email address is valid or invalid on blur.Please suggest me here is my code
This is my php code

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_send_message_to_customer','add_send_msg');?>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="email_customer"  id="email_customer"/>
</form>
<div id="email_info"></div>
<?php
function add_send_msg(){
    $email = isset($_POST['email_customer']) ? $_POST['email_customer'] : null; 
    if( $email ){
        if(is_email($email)){
        $msg = 'valid';
        }
    }
    echo $msg;
    die();
}
```

Adding js and localize script

```
    add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_enqueue_script( "send_email", path_join(WP_PLUGIN_URL,basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/send_email.js', array('jquery')));
   wp_localize_script( 'send_email', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        
}
```

and js file send_email.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("input[name='email_customer']").blur(function (){
        dataString = "email_customer="+jQuery(this).attr("value")+"&action=send_message_to_customer";


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "email_customer="+jQuery(this).attr("value")+"&action=send_message_to_customer",
            url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
            beforeSend: function(){
                jQuery("#email_info").html("Checking Email......");
            },          
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                if( data == 'valid'){
                jQuery("#email_info").html("Email Ok");

            }
            else{
                jQuery("#email_info").html("You have entered invalid email");

            }

        }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is `myajax_script` registered? Also, if you are logged in, you have to add the line `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_message_to_customer','add_send_msg');`

Answer (score 1):

First, don't enqueue on the `init` action. Enqueue on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action for the front end, or the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action for the back end.

Second, the `wp_ajax_*` action will only work for logged in users. For non-logged in users, you must use the `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` action instead. If it needs to work for both, then you must hook both.

Finally, your jQuery.ajax call is missing the "action" of "send_message_to_customer" and the data is in the wrong format. Should look like this:

`data: ['email_customer' : jQuery(this).attr("value") ],
action: 'send_message_to_customer',`

Or possibly just `jQuery(this).val()` instead of the attr() call there. Dunno, didn't try the code myself to test that.

Comment: Still Not Working ..

Comment: So, post the new code that doesn't work in your question. The answer is correct, but I can't know what you changed unless you tell me.

Comment: Yes I think Code is correct but I am unable to know why AJAX response 0

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the 'data' and 'action' like this -

action: 'send_message_to_customer'

data:{'email_customer' : jQuery(this).val()}

Add one more hook -

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_message_to_customer', 'add_send_msg' );

Comment: Still Not Working , Can You please try yourself , if you don't mind...